# Does token parameter change for youtube video info

Tags: download, youtube

When I retrieve the token parameter from the response of the following call:

http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=XXXXXXX

where XXXXXXX is the youtube video id, my understanding is that the token, used for requesting the download of the movie, is different for each video.  However, does this token ever change, or can I retrieve the token once and then trust that it will never change as long as the video id never changes?